# Where I can find the M&B viking conquest companion relationship for current version?

Tags: mount-and-blade-warband, mount-and-blade, mount-and-blade-viking-conquest

What I found is this graph, red arrow stand for dislike, but is this still correct in current version 2.054:

[image]

For example it says Solveig dislike Morgant and Bodo, but [Mount&Blade Wiki](https://mountandblade.fandom.com/wiki/Solveig) says:

[image]

Here is the dislike graph based on M&B wiki:
[image]

Solveig dislike Reginhard and Egil, I don't know if they are both outdated, where I can find the M&B viking conquest companion relationship for current version? Possible to check this in the game file ?

Comment: The answer I have below, that includes likes & dislikes, is based on the most current information (2.054 is Oct-09-2019, the thread which the answer info is from is Nov-14-2019).

Comment: @Smock However there is another Reply #2 on: November 27, 2019, 11:04:23 PM under the same post you give which provide completely different info, how do you know the first one is correct ?

Comment: I've just been looking at [this thread about custom companions](https://forums.taleworlds.com/index.php?topic=130815.0). Is there a module_scripts.py in the VCRE folders anywhere?? You might be able to figure out the personalityclash / personalitymatch objects? I've not got the expansion installed currently but I'll have a look later on.

Answer (score 4):

There's a [thread here on TW forum](https://forums.taleworlds.com/index.php/topic,389048.0.html) that seems to have an updated chart:
Post is from **Nov-14-2019** which is after 2.054 (Oct-09-2019) so should apply to current version.

> [image]
>
> Yellow characters are pagans
>   Blue characters are christians
>
> green arrows means "A" likes "B"
>   red arrows means "A" dislikes "B"
>
> note that not all arrows are bi-directionnal.

(All credit goes to the poster in the TW forum)